# Functions in my code are not being hit. Chrome debugger showing grey highlight when picked and not the usual red. Any idea whats causing the issue?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, debugging

[image: look at lines 156, 164 and 171]
[image: line 237 is the normal color]

Functions are callbacks and this only happens in this particular section of the project. I have researched and have not found anything.

look at lines 156, 164, and 171. Line 237 is the normal color. Every function that has the grey debugger color is not being hit.

Comment: What do you mean by "hit"? If you put console.log('It runs!!') at those places, can you see the log?

Comment: No, I cannot see the log. But if I call the function from the console it runs, but if I call it within my code it does not run.

And it does not even throw an error that the function does not exist.

Comment: Why are you expecting your functions to be run at all? If you can't see the log messages, then they are *truly* not being hit (it has nothing to do with gray highlights).

Where are you invoking those 'dead' functions?

BTW using console doesn't prove anything. Those functions are defined, but maybe not invoked (i.e. not reachable) by the main thread.